# How do I know what my jquery selectors have selected?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, firebug

So I had a general question.  Often, while traversing different tree elements I find that the JQuery selector that I think I need ends up selecting something else, or much worse, it seems to select nothing.

For example sometimes using `.child()` or `.sibling()` it is easy to lose track of what is actually being selected.

Sometimes I can use `alert()`s or a `console.log()` to isolate the problem.  Sometimes though even that doesn't do the trick.  **I was curious whether anyone knew of any good tricks to know what (if anything) the selector I am using has actually selected.**  I don't know if there is any firebug tools, or something else that is useful.

Any suggestions?  Thanks alot.

Comment: I'll usually create the selector in the console before putting it in my page. This is a fast way of seeing what it selects as you can run it straight from the console and make changes on the spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this  [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kflfpppkpdjeodcbbcicnkpbpefebeli) , i don't know if it is available for Firefox also, but you can always try it.

Besides i always `console.log()` everything to make sure i'm selecting the right element, on nested trees for example if you're targeting `div > ul > li > a` I `console.log($(div))` first and then i just add to the jQuery selector

And lastly i just `$(element).css('background-color','red');` so i can locate visually what i'm targeting

Answer (score 1):

Just use the chrome extension and write your selector in console panel eg. `$('div#foobar');` and press enter. It will show the div on the next line. If you take the mouse over the selected div it will show it on the browser.

Once you double click on it it will open it in `elements`.

Same thing works in `firefox` with `firebug extension`. We directly write the selector in firefox `firebug console` to check our selector.

Answer (score 0):

I usually console.log() it to see the [Object object] and from there I can see what's inside, or if i'm manipulating specific things, a lot of times i'll do a quick

`$(element).css('background', '#000');`

Just to visually see it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to save the result of the query in a variable and check it's "length" property. If length>0, you've selected something.

Example:

```
var $listItem = $("li");
if($listItem.length>0) doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the following ways.
`console.log($('.myElementClass'));` when you hover the element on `firebug console` you can see your element being highlighted, so you can see if it's the right element or not.
`alert($('.myElementClass').length);`